# Flask sqlAlchemy validation issue with flask_Marshmallow

Tags: python, exception, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

Using flask_marshmallow for input validation, with scheme.load() , I'm unable to capture the errors generated by the @validates decorator in the model

I captured the result and errors in the resource but errors are sent directly to the users

## ==========model.py==========

````
```python

from sqlalchemy.orm import validates

from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload


db = SQLAlchemy()
ma = Marshmallow()

class Company(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "company"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    addressLine1 = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    addressLine2 = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    city = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    state = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    zipCode = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    logo = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    website = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    recognition = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    vision = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    history = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    mission = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    jobs = relationship("Job", cascade="all, delete-orphan")

    def save_to_db(self):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()

    @validates('name')
    def validate_name(self, key, name):
        print("=====inside validate_name=======")
        if not name:
            raise AssertionError('No Company name provided')

        if Company.query.filter(Company.name == name).first():
            raise AssertionError('Company name is already in use')

        if len(name) < 4 or len(name) > 120:
            raise AssertionError('Company  name must be between 3 and 120 characters')

        return name

```
````

#### ==========schemas_company.py==============

````
```python
from ma import ma
from models.model import Company


class CompanySchema(ma.ModelSchema):

    class Meta:
        model = Company
```
````

## =============resources_company.py

````
```python
from schemas.company import CompanySchema
company_schema = CompanySchema(exclude='jobs')


COMPANY_ALREADY_EXIST = "A company with the same name already exists"
COMPANY_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY = "The company was sucessfully created"


@api.route('/company')
class Company(Resource):

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Creating a new Company """
        data = request.get_json(force=True)
        schema = CompanySchema()
        if data:
            logger.info("Data got by /api/test/testId methd %s" % data)


            # Validation with schema.load() OPTION_2
            company, errors = schema.load(data)
            print(company)
            print(errors)

            if errors:
                return {"errors": errors}, 422
            company.save_to_db()
            return {"message": COMPANY_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY}, 201

```
````

## ===========REQUEST==========

This is the POST request coming from the user

```
{
    "name": "123",
    "addressLine1": "400 S Royal King Ave",
    "addressLine2": "Suite 356",
    "city": "Miami",
    "state": "FL",
    "zipCode": "88377",
    "logo": "This is the logo",
    "website": "http://www.python.com",
    "recognition": "Most innovated company in the USA 2018-2019",
    "vision": "We want to change for better all that needs to be changed",
    "history": "Created in 2016 with the objective of automate all needed process",
    "mission": " Our mission is to find solutions to old problems"
}
```

**====ISSUE DESCRIPTION======**

The  above POST request generates an AssertionError exception as per validate_name function in model.py as under:

```
File "code/models/model.py", line 95, in validate_name
raise AssertionError('Company  name must be between 3 and 120 characters')
AssertionError: Company  name must be between 3 and 120 characters
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2018 13:44:58] "POST /api/company HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

So the response that returns to the user is this useless error messages

```
{
    "message": "Internal Server Error"
}
```

**My question is:**

**What I have to do so the raised AssertionError message is sent to the users instead of this ugly   error message?**

```
AssertionError message
{
   "message": "Company  name must be between 3 and 120 characters" 
}

Exception 
{
    "message": "Internal Server Error"
}
```

I thought the error would capture the exception generated by @validates('name'), but looks like it is not the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.
I changed the schema as under:

```
from ma import ma
from models.model import Company

from marshmallow import fields, validate


class CompanySchema(ma.ModelSchema):

    name = fields.Str(required=True, validate=[validate.Length(min=4, max=250)])
    addressLine1 = fields.Str(required=True, validate=[validate.Length(min=5, max=250)])
    addressLine2 = fields.Str(required=False, validate=[validate.Length(max=250)])
    city = fields.Str(required=True, validate=[validate.Length(min=5, max=100)])
    state = fields.Str(required=True, validate=[validate.Length(min=2, max=10)])
    zipCode = fields.Str(required=True, validate=[validate.Length(min=5, max=250)])
    logo = fields.Str(required=False, validate=[validate.Length(max=250)])
    website = fields.Str(required=True, validate=[validate.Length(min=5, max=250)])
    recognition = fields.Str(required=False, validate=[validate.Length(max=250)])
    vision = fields.Str(required=False, validate=[validate.Length(max=250)])
    history = fields.Str(required=False, validate=[validate.Length(max=250)])
    mission = fields.Str(required=False, validate=[validate.Length(max=250)])

    class Meta:
        model = Company
```

Now I do not validate anything in my model so my model is just

```
class Company(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "company"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    addressLine1 = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    addressLine2 = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    city = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    state = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    zipCode = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    logo = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    website = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    recognition = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    vision = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    history = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    mission = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    jobs = relationship("Job", cascade="all, delete-orphan")

    def save_to_db(self):
        print("=====inside save_to_db=======")
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()
```

So in the resource(view) endpoint, I have:

```
@api.route('/company')
class Company(Resource):

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Creating a new Company """
        data = request.get_json(force=True)
        schema = CompanySchema()
        if data:
            logger.info("Data got by /api/test/testId method %s" % data)

            # Validation with schema.load() OPTION_2
            company, errors = schema.load(data)
            print(company)

            if errors:
                return {"errors": errors}, 422

            company.save_to_db()
            return {"message": COMPANY_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY}, 201
```

So now when a user makes a wrong request with a name under 4 characters long, I'm able to return a beautiful error response to the user as under

```
{
    "errors": {
        "name": [
            "Length must be between 4 and 250."
        ]
    }
}
```

But if you noted why I did and the "pattern" I used you will see the following details

1. -Using flask_marshmallow for serialization and deserialization.
2. -In my  model, I used marshmallow (not flask_marshmallow) for validation
3. -Validation works with the schema.load()
4. -I wonder how would I be able to add more complex validation to the input than the one I used?
5. -Is this a good pattern to follow, What improvement can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What I do is make a method instead of marshmallow's load

```
def json_loader(schema, json):
    try:
        assert json is not None, "request body is required"
    except AssertionError as assertionError:
        raise InvalidUsage(40001, assertionError.args[0], 400)
    result = schema.load(json)
    if result.errors:
        raise InvalidUsage(40001, result.errors, 400)
    else:
        return result.data
```

However, if using the 3.0 version. They have changed this part. Here it's their example.

```
from marshmallow import ValidationError

try:
    result = UserSchema().load({'name': 'John', 'email': 'foo'})
except ValidationError as err:
    err.messages  # => {'email': ['"foo" is not a valid email address.']}
    valid_data = err.valid_data  # => {'name': 'John'}
```

https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/quickstart.html#validation

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is not too late,
The below example is a working example of getting errors displayed to the api response.

**The trick is to use validate method that returns error dictionary, or rather a list of dictionaries of errors that can be displayed to the user.**

```
from flask import request
import datetime as dt
from marshmallow import (
    Schema,RAISE,fields,pprint,validate,ValidationError,post_load)
from flask_restplus import Api,Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app, prefix="/api/v1")

class User:
    def __init__(self, name,email,age,permission):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.age = age
        self.permission = permission
        self.created_at = dt.datetime.utcnow()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "User(name={})".format(self.name)

class Userschema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str(required=True,validate=[validate.Length(min=1)])
    email = fields.Email(required=True,validate=[validate.Length(min=1)])
    permission = fields.Str(validate=[validate.OneOf(["read","write","admin"])])
    age = fields.Int(validate=[validate.Range(min=10,max=30)])

    @post_load
    def make_user(self,data,**kwargs):
        return User(**data)

users = [] 


class UserCollection(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {"subscriberList":users}

    def post(self,*args,**kwargs):
        schema = Userschema()
        data = request.get_json(force=True)
        errors = schema.validate(api.payload)
        if errors:
            return errors, 422       
        user=schema.load(data)
        result = schema.dump(user)
        users.append(result)

        return {"msg": "Subscriber added"},201


api.add_resource(UserCollection,'/subscribers')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Request && Response**

`http://localhost:5000/api/v1/subscribers`

**Post body**

`{
    "name": "derrick",
    "permission": "esc",
    "age": 2,
    "email":"me@gmail"
}`

**Response**

`{
    "email": [
        "Not a valid email address."
    ],
    "permission": [
        "Must be one of: read, write, admin."
    ],
    "age": [
        "Must be greater than or equal to 10 and less than or equal to 30."
    ]
}`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps take a look at:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/errorhandling/

You can likely register a `handler` for your `AssertionError`.

Comment: Thank you for your response and your time. I however found a solution to my issue that I will put below.Still I find the below solution is not exactly what I thought .I still think there should be a good explanation to below solution

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error in your code is that you raise `AssertionError` in the validator instead of marshmallow's `ValidationError`.

Your answer goes in the right direction, creating a schema that uses marshmallow validators (`required`, `Length`,...). You can add custom validation by defining other validators (field or schema validators).

You could use [webargs](https://webargs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to validate the inputs rather than validate manually in the view function. It uses marshmallow internally and it is maintained by the marshmallow team.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will give your solution a try and get back to you.Also thank you for your recommendation on using webargs.