# OOP class design advice. Can a class instantiate and use another class that inherits from the same parent class?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

Currently in a situation where I have a series of classes that turn an API request JSON into objects. The objects are modeled after my database schema. I think the part that I'm struggling with is how to represent those entity relationships that are formed with foreign keys in my database.

The following classes are just for an example, the instance variables are much different for my application's schema.

```
class Table(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        # stuff
        
    @abstractmethod
    def validateSchema(self):
        """Validates the resources column values."""
        pass


class ClassRoom(Table):
    def __init__(self, id, location_id, location):
        super().__init__()
        self.id = id
        self.location = Location(location_id, location)
        
    def validateSchema(self):
        # stuff

class Location(Table):
    def __init__(self, id, location):
        super().__init__()
        self.id = id
        self.location = location
        
    def validateSchema(self):
        # stuff
```

The part I'm concerned about is when I am creating an object of the same type as the class that has the object as an instance variable.

```
class ClassRoom(Table):
    def __init__(self, id, location_id, location):
        
        # Can I instantiate this class even if it inherits the same parent?
        self.location = Location(location_id, location)
```

Is this ok in OOP? Is there a better way to design my classes?

Also, these classes are just defined for the request JSONs that get sent to my API. Their purpose will be to facilitate column validation and a few other purposes. The specific validation I am hoping to implement in these classes comes from this other Stackoverflow post [Flask sqlAlchemy validation issue with flask_Marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53980885/flask-sqlalchemy-validation-issue-with-flask-marshmallow). I'm not trying to recreate SqlAlchemy here.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having references to sibling classes. The two objects are totally independent.

Comment: Ok that's good to know. Do you see an issue with my design then?

Comment: It seems OK. But why wouldn't it be `def __init__(self, id, location):` and create the `Location` object in the caller?

Comment: The way you're doing it, every `Classroom` will have a reference to a different `Location` object, even if they're actually in the same location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Table` class is analogous to SqlAlchemy's `db.Model` class. And just as it can have references between different subclasses, so can you.

The specific design of your `Classroom.__init__()` method seems wrong. All the  classrooms in the same location should have references to the same `Location` object, but you create a new one for each classroom. The `Location` should be a parameter, rather than the location ID and name.

```
class ClassRoom(Table):
    def __init__(self, id, location):
        super().__init__()
        self.id = id
        self.location = location
```

Then you can create multiple classrooms in a location:

```
loc = Location(loc_id, loc_name)
c1 = Classroom(c1_id, loc)
c2 = Classroom(c2_id, loc)
```

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to answer my question. Also, thanks for answering my original question and going even further to help out with my design.